# Extra Legend in Matplotlib Plot

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I have the legend that matplotlib created from the data, but I would like to add an extra legend with some other information I need to include.
How can I do that?

I am new to Python and I read several forums, but I can't find anything on this

Comment: This page has several options to add text to a figure: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add the different legends to your plot. You can add more than one legend to your plot by using .add_artist.

```
data1 = plt.scatter([1, 2, 3],[3,2,1])
data2 = plt.scatter([4,6,7],[3,2,8])

# Create a legend
legend_1 = plt.legend(handles=[data1])

# Add the legend to the current Axes.
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(legend_1)

# Create another legend for the second line.
plt.legend(handles=[data2])
```

More info on the legend guide: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes